# How can I use order by in a SQL subselect?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, sql-order-by, subquery

I have an aggregate function called ConcatList that concatenates a list of values into a single comma separated value.

Here is an example of what I am trying to do. I have two tables: Employee and Job. Job is a "child" of Employee. I need to get a list of the employees that includes a comma-delimited list of the jobs related to the employee, sorted by the name of the job.

I thought I could do this:

```
select em.EmployeeId,
       em.EmployeeName,
       (select ConcatList(jo.JobName)
          from Job jo
         where jo.EmployeeId = em.EmployeeId
         order by jo.JobName)
  from Employee em;
```

However, this returns me the following error on the "order by" clause:

```
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
```

If I get rid of the "order by" clause, this SQL works, but I need to sort the list of jobs.

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort the joined records and then aggregate the result:

```
select EmployeeId,
       EmployeeName,
       ConcatList(JobName)   
from (
    select em.EmployeeId,
           em.EmployeeName,
           jo.JobName
      from Employee em 
      join Job jo
        on jo.EmployeeId = em.EmployeeId
     order by jo.JobName 
      )
group by EmployeeId,
         EmployeeName
```

Comment: If you use the distinct keyword in your from clause, this solution works.

Answer (score 1):

Since `ConcatList` is a user-defined aggregate function, it would seem to makes sense either to modify `ConcatList` to order the results or to create a `ConcatSortedList` aggregate function that sorts the data it aggregates.  Gary Myers has an example of a [user-defined aggregate function that produces a sorted list](http://blog.sydoracle.com/2005/12/new-variant-on-stragg-ordered.html).

You can also go through the various [string aggregation techniques](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/StringAggregationTechniques.php) on Tim Hall's site.  If you have to produce a sorted list, using many of those techniques would be easier than trying to guarantee that a non-sorting user-defined aggregate function produces a sorted result.  The [generic function taking a REF CURSOR](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/StringAggregationTechniques.php#generic_function_using_ref_cursor), for example, is relatively easy to use when sorting is required because you can just add an `ORDER BY` to the cursor.

Answer (score 0):

```
select em.EmployeeId,
       em.EmployeeName,
       wm_concat(jo.JobName) over 
          (partion by jo.EmployeeID order by JobName) as JobList
  from Employee em
  INNER JOIN JOB JO on jo.EmployeeId = em.EmployeeId
```

Example from which I realized wm_concat is an analytic --> http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1629662

Text2 = random text

val = grouping

```
Select val, text2, wm_concat(text2) over (partition by val order by text2) as out_text2 
from B


Test results:
VAL     text2                    out_Text2
1   XXX010105                   (CLOB) XXX010105
1   something XXX010101 somet   (CLOB) XXX010105,...
2   yet another XXX010102 and   (CLOB) yet anothe...
4   XXX010103                   (CLOB) XXX010103
5   a                           (CLOB) a
5   b                           (CLOB) a,b
5   c                           (CLOB) a,b,c
5   x                           (CLOB) a,b,c,x
6   a                           (CLOB) a
6   g                           (CLOB) a,g
6   i                           (CLOB) a,g,i
6   n                           (CLOB) a,g,i,n
6   x                           (CLOB) a,g,i,n,x
```